# My name was misspelled in a citation, what should I do?

Tags: citations, errors-erratum, personal-name

Recently, a newly published paper in a journal cited one of our papers and managed to misspell my name in the reference list. How should I deal with this? Simply ignore this? Or should I contact the authors or publisher to mention this?

Comment: I had a similar case. I mailed the publisher, not expecting much, and surprisingly they fixed it.

Comment: dsfgsho is an easy to misspell name!

Comment: My last name, `Mallett`, is apparently _impossible_ to spell correctly.  From citations to speaker announcers to diplomata--what I can't understand is why, if you're unsure about it, you can't just copy it directly?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: On a more serious note, I never understood why misspelling names happens. I realise while I have a lousy memory for names, I never had problems spelling them right; however, many people seem to have problems with that, e.g. when spelling "Stephan" vs. "Stefan". That doubly especially considering we live in the Age of Copy and Paste.

Comment: @phresnel Indeed in the age of Google and copy paste misspelling a name is quite an error. Its easier just to copy it from the paper you want to cite!

Comment: @AnderBiguri: The only reason against Copy+Paste is when it copies text-formatting, but then, just open an editor or your browser url box, paste there, copy again and the formatting is gone.

Comment: @phresnel I will say even more: If you do bibliographies in BibTex (as many researchers do) the online journals have the WHOLE bibliography data downloadable usually. Its even easier

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Yep. And you can build up your database at home, if you write papers often. But then, even academic folk is often not into DRY- or other quality principles.

Comment: The easiest solution is to legally change your name to match that on the article.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: *Never* trust the downloadable bibliography data without comparing it to the author info explicitly given in the paper. For an example, enjoy [this publication by *two* authors](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1333459&tag=1), or [this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1232094), whzich has one author in common with the first example.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Im new in the publication world, but, you are telling me that the data that the jornals give you MAY be wrong? Thats impresive and unexpected

Comment: @AnderBiguri: The metadata seems to be extracted automatically by various publishers for their digital libraries, and the accuracy of that extracted data ... varies. Especially when names with non-ASCII characters are involved (and thus possibly one of the sets of names that you'd be most motivated to copy and paste/import from a BibTeX file rather than re-type).

Comment: @AnderBiguri: And while I'm at it, when I suspect the author's name might have lost an accent or so already on the PDF version of the paper, I always check the author's personal website to see how they spell themselves there.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes. Publisher bibtex entries are of horrible quality. Look for yourself: choose a paper whose author's name has an accent, and check if it's properly escaped with Latex commands. Or choose a paper whose title has an all-capital acronym, and check if the acronym is correctly enclosed in an additional pair braces. Or choose an author who has a double name or surname, and check if the authors are in the correct format "Surname1, Name1 and Surname2, Name2 and Surname3, Name3".

Comment: I once had my name _removed completely_ from the author list of a citation. Worse still, it was one of my coauthors on the paper in question that made the mistake.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In addition to sending an e-mail to the journal, as suggested already, you should **check the most common academic databases** such as Scopus and Web of Knowledge/Science and **submit corrections** to them so that they pick up the citation correctly. They have a form to submit this kind of corrections automatically; it will then take a few weeks to apply them.

People often (way *too* often, actually) rely on these databases to measure the performance of academics, so it is important that they don't miss any of your citations.

Answer (score 7):

You may send an email to either the publisher, editor of the journal or even the corresponding author of the paper and inform them about the misspelling. They *may* edit the misspelling.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of services that assign unique identifiers to authors and then associate publications with a particular author. This is particularly helpful for identifying publications of authors that have common names (“John A. Smith.”)  For example, Thomson Reuters (who publish the “Web of Science” database) have “[ResearcherID](http://www.researchid.com)”. Another important service is [ORCID](http://orcid.org/). You should register yourself with these services and establish your connection to your papers. You should also decide now on one version of your name (e.g. whether to use a middle initial or full middle name) and try to stick with it through out your career.

It may or may not be possible to get the journal to correct the spelling of your name in the online version of the paper. It certainly will not be possible to get this fixed in printed volumes that have already been distributed. That is why it is particularly important to check this information in reviewing page proofs before the paper is published.

Comment: The spelling error is in a paper written by *someone else*, in their references.